# How to tell LDAP SSL server with multiple certificates to return the one that I need?

Tags: authentication, ssl, active-directory, ldap

My simple LDAP java program, using

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");  
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");  
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, <UserDN>);  
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, <Password>);  
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");  
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://<host>:636");
```

to make LDAP SSL authentication stopped working ever since a 2nd server certificate with the same CN but other details in the subject are different was installed on the server which I don't have access at all.

The program fails when I make the initial context

```
new InitialDirContext(env);
```

The error is "*Failed to initialize directory context: <host>:636*"

---

It returns the 2nd server certificate when I run

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <host>:636 </dev/null
```

that makes me believe that the solution will be to find a way to tell the server which certificate to use.

I search and read a lot of articles on this topic and I have to admit that I am very confused, it is not clear to me if these articles are talking about client certificate or server certificate, or the actions to be taken are for the client side, or server side.

In one article, it says that I can use a custom SSLSocketFactory with the keystore path and

```
env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "com.xxx.MyCustomSSLSocketFactory");
```

But I don't know the path to the server certificate keystore on the server.

In one Microsoft article, it says the best resolution is to have just one server certificate on the server or to put the server certificate to Active Directory Domain Services (NTDS\Personal) certificate store for LDAPS communications.  But I don't have access to the server and the 'fix' to this problem has to be done in my LDAP java program.

In another article, it says to use Server Name Indication (SNI) extension.

So is there a way that I can specify which certificate I want to the server?  Or my problem is somewhere else?

Thanks a lot.

---

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: <host>:636; socket closed
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:419)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.ldapBind(LdapClient.java:340)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:192)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2694)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:293)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:175)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:136)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:66)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:82)
```

When I used Jxplorer to run the same test, it gave me the same error.

EJP was right to point out that the issue was that the certificate was not trusted. Many thanks EJP.

When I installed the CA Certificate in %JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts, Jxplorer worked.  My program still failed.  I had to add these lines in it to make it work (not sure if I need all of them though ...):

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",%JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",%JAVA_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit);
```

But since the certificate is not trusted in the first place, I simply 'force' our server to trust it, hence this solution is not acceptable.  And neither our server nor the LDAP server runs with Java 7.  So SNI is out too!

EJP mentioned that I could control the server certificate by restricting the cipher suites or accepted issuers in the client (my webapp), if the server certificates have different algorithms or issuers.  The 2 certificates do have different issuers, however, I don't know how to do that and I could not find anything on that neither.

EJP can you please elaborate, or point me to some sites ... ?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: EJP, once again thanks.  Unfortunately no stack trace is available.  But the error happens when the initial context is made: new InitialDirContext(env), and the error says it fails to initialize directory Context: <host>:636

Comment: The error is an exception, and it has a stack trace. You must print it, and post it here. You will probably also have to run your client with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` and post the results here.

Comment: The stack trace is not written to the log, only the error message is.  And the code is run in a server that has connection with the external LDAP server, my local machine does not.  And the code is compiled into a jar called by a webservice.  I cannot simply go there and add the code to write out the stack trace.

Comment: Then your question can't be answered, sorry. You are just going to have to take those steps.

Comment: But can it be done - to tell the server that we want the first certificate, not the second one?  In the mean time, I will get the stack trace written to the log ... but that will take a day or two, to go through the 'procedure'.

Comment: You can control the server certificate by restricting the cipher suites or accepted issuers in the client (your webapp), if the server certificates have different algorithms or issuers. Otherwise you may have to use SNI in the app, however you do that. It's supported in Java 7: see the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). Not that I think any of this is the anwer. It's more likely a truststore problem: the certificate you were getting before was trusted, this one isn't.

Comment: Many thanks EJP for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

Comment: Surely there is more of it than that? There should be an `SSLException` of some kind under it.

Comment: The rest of the stack trace is from my program: at com.xxx.authentication.search(authentication.java:465) where I made the call new InitialDirContext(env);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the certificates have different issuers, you can control which certificate you get at the client by controlling which of those issuers is in your truststore. If only one of them is, that's the one you'll get. If they're both there, you get pot luck. Note that if your truststore also contains a common super-issuer, again it's probably pot luck.

Comment: Many many thanks EJP.  I removed the 4 java setProperty from my program, removed the untrusted certificate and installed the trusted one.  And it worked!  I spent a lot of time reading SSL LDAP authentication materials for my problem, and I did not come across anyone mentioning your solution, and yet it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The result isn't pot luck if you specify one and only one certificate in the Certificates - Service (Active Directory Domain Service) -  NTDS\Personal location in Microsoft Management Console. Contrary to Microsoft docs I've read, though, a domain controller restart seemed to be necessary for the newly specified certificate to 'take hold'.